# Python os.popen and unicode

Tags: python, unicode

I'm working on (French) PC with Python 3.4

`for line in os.popen('dir'):
    print(line.rstrip())`

I get the first line as expected

```
Le volume dans le lecteur C s'appelle SYSTEME
```

but for the second (with **é**)

Le numéro de s**é**rie du volume est C250-47DD

I get the error message :

```
return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_map)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u201a' in position 7: character maps to
 <undefined>
```

What can I do ?
In advance thanks for your help

Comment: you should use subprocess *Deprecated since version 2.6: This function is obsolete.*, or  just use  os.listdir.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [os.popen().read() - charmap decoding error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42033334/os-popen-read-charmap-decoding-error)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to encode your line before printing by proper encoding  :

```
for line in os.popen('dir'): 
      print(line.rstrip().encode('UTF-8')) # as utf8 is a universal encoding i use it you can use another too
```

Comment: [Doesn't seem to work...?](https://tio.run/##HcgxDoAgDADAWV5BWKCDxMSF@BY3hchg29Sa4OvRuF2OHz0I597rySRq6TKFxDZb8XNk4oxBPEtFLdatLU3Ow2KGf0KLcqlUDhAzbrTn4G8tY/IAvb8) or is this windows-only? (by the way there is a (newer...) duplicate to the question)